# display weekly booking report

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to display a report of all employees for a particular service provider for the current week/month, whether they were booked or free per hour.

This is my source data table:

```
SELECT 
       DATE(start_time) AS "date"
      ,DAYNAME(start_time) AS "weekday"
      ,account.name AS "employee"
      ,appointment.id AS "appointment"
      ,appointment.start_time
      ,appointment.end_date
FROM appointment
   INNER JOIN employee ON appointment.employee = employee.id
   INNER JOIN account ON employee.account = account.id
ORDER BY date
```

with the following result:

[image]

So, the goal is to transpose the previous result into the following table format (only two employees are displayed on this screenshot).

[image]

As you could see in the source data table, an appointment could be booked (or covered) in several time slots of one hour (in my table that is appointment id = 2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, answering my own question:

```
SELECT
  account.name AS "employee"
 ,DATE_FORMAT(working_hours.hour, '%H:%i') as "hours"
 ,SUM(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(start_time) = 2 AND HOUR(working_hours.hour) = HOUR(start_time) THEN 1 END) AS "monday"
 ,SUM(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(start_time) = 3 AND HOUR(working_hours.hour) = HOUR(start_time) THEN 1 END) AS "tuesday"
 ,SUM(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(start_time) = 4 AND HOUR(working_hours.hour) = HOUR(start_time) THEN 1 END) AS "wednesday"
 ,SUM(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(start_time) = 5 AND HOUR(working_hours.hour) = HOUR(start_time) THEN 1 END) AS "thursday"
 ,SUM(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(start_time) = 6 AND HOUR(working_hours.hour) = HOUR(start_time) THEN 1 END) AS "friday"
 ,SUM(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(start_time) = 7 AND HOUR(working_hours.hour) = HOUR(start_time) THEN 1 END) AS "saturday"
 ,SUM(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(start_time) = 1 AND HOUR(working_hours.hour) = HOUR(start_time) THEN 1 END) AS "sunday"            
FROM appointment
  CROSS JOIN working_hours
  INNER JOIN employee ON appointment.employee = employee.id
  INNER JOIN account ON employee.account = account.id
  INNER JOIN provider ON employee.provider = provider.id  
WHERE provider.id = 1 AND WEEK(start_time) = 25
GROUP BY hour, employee.id
ORDER BY employee.id, hours
```

And this is the exactly the result I wanted:

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).